# Please help identify capacitor - turntable motor drive PCB

Tags: capacitor, identification

My Rega Planar 3 turntable is belt driven. It has been a year in storage, and now the platter spins backwards. A Google search suggests that one of the motor capacitors is to blame.

I reckon I'll replace both, as the turntable is over 20 years old. But since this is a 220 V circuit, I don't feel comfortable basing my actions on assumptions, hence this question.

Here is a picture of the PCB that drives the motor.

[image: The two components on the motor PCB]

The PCB is driving a "PREMOTEC 9904 111 31813" 50Hz 110V synchronous motor, even though the turntable is rated for a 50Hz 220V line. (Am I looking at a capacitive dropper?)

These two caps are the only components on the PCB (Update: I also found a 1MΩ bleeder resistor hiding under the Rifa). In addition, there's the motor, and a mains switch, and that's the whole circuit.

Here is a picture of the traces:

[image: The underside of the PCB]

And here is the whole compartment. The white wires go to the mains switch.

[image: The whole compartment]

An attempt at a schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2ZWBl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**First, to get the yellow capacitor (C1) out of the way**:

It is a Rifa that hasn't gone boom yet.

- The top is marked 220n X2
- One side (visible in the picture) is marked 275 V ~ SH
- The other side is marked  RIFA / PME 271 M / 40/100/56/B / 250VAC / K5

I suppose I can replace this one with any 220nF X2 class 275V rated mains filter cap, am I right?

**The white one (C2) is harder.**

- The top is marked 220n K J0 (OR JO?)
- One side (visible in the picture) is marked EVOX / MMK / 400-
- The other side is blank.

So my main question is: What type of capacitor is this? Or rather; What type of capacitor is it safe to replace this one with?

Comment: No idea but serious respect just for having a Rega Planar 3 - I remember earlier RPs when they came out. Nice one.

Comment: Excellent deck. Recently dug my RP3 from the late 80's out of storage and going to do a refurb before my daughter has it. Paired with a decent cartridge it sounded great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MMK is a metallized polyester film capacitor.

220n is 220 nanofarads.

K is 10% tolerance.

It is rated for 400V.

Comment: Better make that 400 V AC.

Answer (score 1):

It's an AC synchronous motor.  The red and blue leads should both have same voltage applied to them, but with the phase 90 degrees apart, which is what C2 provides.  The R1/C1 combo drops the voltage down and probably tweaks the phase or load a little better.

The manufacture datasheet for the motor shows a slightly different circuit, with a 6.8k ohm 2.5W resistor replacing R1/C1 to drop the motor voltage to ~120V and C2 remaining the same.  I have an early 80s Rega Planar 2 and it has a 12k ohm instead of R1/C1.  A larger than recommended value is used since the motor runs a bit smoother with the lower voltage (around 80-90VAC).